# How to accurately shift subtitles

Tags: video, avi, subtitles

I'm trying to hardsub an avi file. I made subtitles for it using a different avi file. There is a small time difference betweeen the two files, so I need to shift the timing of the subtitles a little bit. I have done this before using Subtitle Workshop, but the method I used was not very accurate. It requires using the slider and is quite painful. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think this [subtitle post](http://superuser.com/questions/49245/what-subtitle-file-editor-for-srt-files-supports-synchronization/49278#49278)can help. do read your `.srt` file and note down first dialogue and note the occurrence of that dialogue. that can help you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to adjust timings for all subtitles in a single file with Subtitle Workshop:

1: Edit > timings > Set Delay, set a positive or negative delay time, select the "All subtitles" radio button, Apply.

2: Select all the subtitles: Ctrl+A, to add 100 milliseconds delay, press Shift+Ctrl+H, to subtract 100 milliseconds, press Shift+Ctrl+N. You can hold each of these key combinations down to rapidly increase or decrease the times.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier using Aegisub.

Just go to Timing and add/decrease the time to your subs

Then, you can play line by line to see if the edit is synced or not